# Primeng datatable on complete loading?

Tags: angular, rxjs, primeng

Hi am using Primeng dataTable to render database query results from backend, is there any event firing once the columns and rows are displayed?

Longer question, am going to block the screen while querying the backend, was unblocking the screen once the request returns, but seem there is a slight delay between the screen has unblocked (request returned) and the result data being seen on screen (rows and columns populated), we are talking about something like 100~500ms delay. So I want to unblock the screen not at the request returns but wait until data is seen.

Prefer answers not to change Primeng datatable, unless it is the only option. Open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the BlockUI.
It can block the datatable based on a boolean parameter.
Sample:

```
<p-blockUI [target]="dt" [blocked]="blockedPanel">
  <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x" style="position:absolute;top:25%;left:50%"></i>
</p-blockUI>
```

And your datatable:

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="myList"></p-dataTable>
```

In your ts file you can set/unset the boolean flag which is named "blockedPanel" here.
[Reference](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/blockui)

This would work in case the dataset is small and the delay is not noticeable.

Another alternative would be to try the

> onValueChange()

method which would trigger on the dataset change.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am doing. The key point in the question is "when" to unblock. As in your saying, when to unset the boolean flag. I unset the boolean flag when the request returns but that is too soon. I wonder if dataTable has an event firing once the data is loaded.

Comment: Did you try the onValueChange() event?

Comment: Oh good, it does have an onValueChange() event now (my version was a bit older than when they added this new event), tested, looks good. If you can add this to your answer above (instead of a comment below) I can pick yours as the answer, thank you.

Comment: @user1589188 Done.